# How to change colour of text using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm just beginning to learn jQuery and I'm trying to change the colour of a piece of text on my webpage when the user scrolls. the piece of text is contained within a div id. The name of the div I am using in my CSS sheet is #headerTitle.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).scroll(function(){

        $("#headerTitle").backgroundColor({
            transition:"background-color": "green"
         });
    }   
}
```

Comment: If you [search the official jQuery documentation for `backgroundColor`](https://api.jquery.com/?s=backgroundColor), you will see that no such method exists. It's good that you tried something, but reading the documentation *beforehand* saves you from going in the wrong direction. You can change CSS via https://api.jquery.com/css/ and the property that controls the text color is `color`. [Learn how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging).

Comment: Your questions title and description are talking about two different things. Title refers to text color, but your description is talking about the background color of a div. Can you clarify what you are needing?

Comment: @MattGreen Sorry about that I am trying to change the text colour, not the background colour.

Comment: Ah figured that was it, I updated my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        alert('The Window Scrolled');
        // Set the color attribute on the div
        $('#headerTitle').css('color', 'red');
    });
   });
```

When the window scrolls you are 'alerted' (This makes sure it works, you can delete), then it will set the `text` color within your div using the jQuery [CSS](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method.

Comment: What does `this` refer to here? How exactly should the OP use it with the code he has?